# If God were going to send another Biblical flood, would He warn us?

Tags: flood-of-noah, papacy, prophets

It goes without saying - Before 'The Flood of Noah', God warned Noah that it was coming.

But I wonder - If most of humanity turned evil again, and God was about to send another Biblical flood, would He warn us? And if so, would He warn us by way of the Pope? Or would he tell a prophet?

Basically I'm wondering if there's anything in the Bible or in any Christian teaching which would give us reason to believe that God would send advance warning of another flood.

Comment: Genesis outlines that God promises to never again destroy the world by flood.

Comment: And Noah warned the people.

Comment: This is a truth question and should be historically locked, though the bounty prevents that.

Comment: See Genesis 9:11; Isaiah 54:9. God is never going to destroy the whole earth by flood again.

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer beyond what has been offered?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question, as God has sworn that He would not revisit this particular judgement. This, necessarily, requires a hypothetical answer (opinion). ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question seems to assume the Genesis account is literal, so I'll answer from the YEC view, which assumes it's literal.

<sup>The usual disclaimer - not all denominations assume the Genesis account is actual history, I'm just answering as if it is, since the question seems to be looking for that viewpoint.</sup>

From **Genesis 9 (KJV)**

> And God spake unto Noah, and to his sons with him, saying, And
>   I, behold, I establish my covenant with you, and with your seed after
>   you; and with every living creature that is with you, of the fowl,
>   of the cattle, and of every beast of the earth with you; from all that
>   go out of the ark, to every beast of the earth. And I will
>   establish my covenant with you; **neither shall all flesh be cut off any
>   more by the waters of a flood; neither shall there any more be a flood
>   to destroy the earth.** And God said, This is the token of the
>   covenant which I make between me and you, and every living creature
>   that is with you, for perpetual generations: I do set my bow in
>   the cloud, and it shall be for a token of a covenant between me and
>   the earth. And it shall come to pass, when I bring a cloud over
>   the earth, that the  bow shall be seen in the cloud:

In the above passage, God promised to never send another flood.  Therefore, if [God cannot lie](http://www.apologeticspress.org/APContent.aspx?category=12&article=1383), there is no chance of Him flooding the earth, so it would be futile to ponder whether He would tell us ahead of time.

However.. God HAS promised that He will judge the earth in the future.

From **Revelation 21 (KJV)**

> And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the
>   first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea. And I John
>   saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven,
>   prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. And I heard a great
>   voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men,
>   and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people, and God
>   himself shall be with them, and be their God. And God shall wipe away
>   all tears from their eyes; and there shall be no more death, neither
>   sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the
>   former things are passed away.

2 Peter 3:10 even says how it will happen. It will be with great heat, not water. (Again, KJV)

> But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night; in the
>   which the heavens shall pass away with a great noise, and the elements
>   shall melt with fervent heat, the earth also and the works that are
>   therein shall be burned up.

So, we can say that if God were to destroy the earth, He ***would*** warn us - because He already has.

Comment: And you beat me to the Genesis reference :)

Comment: I'd add something from one of those verses that describe him coming "like a thief in the night" (for example) and add that we won't get any new warnings beyond what is already in scripture.

Comment: @AffableGeek already seems to have included that angle.  Once again, I find myself looking at his answer and thinking "Why didn't I think of including that!?!?"

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr>**

### 1. He already has warned us

### 2. We refuse to listen

---

At the conclusion of the story of Lazarus and the Rich Man (Luke 16), Lazarus pleads with Abraham to go warn his brothers about the fires of hell. The story continues:

> "'No, father Abraham,' he said, 'but if someone from the dead goes to them, they will repent.'
>
> "He said to him, 'If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not be convinced even if someone rises from the dead.'"

The implication here (listing 'Moses and the Prophets') is that people had been warned *via the Scriptures* of the wrath that is to come.

Jesus was likewise asked for signs, and was rather insistent back in Luke 11, when he said:

> "This is a wicked generation. It asks for a sign, but none will be given it except the sign of Jonah. For as Jonah was a sign to the Ninevites, so also will the Son of Man be to this generation. The Queen of the South will rise at the judgment with the people of this generation and condemn them, for she came from the ends of the earth to listen to Solomon’s wisdom; and now something greater than Solomon is here. The men of Nineveh will stand up at the judgment with this generation and condemn it, for they repented at the preaching of Jonah; and now something greater than Jonah is here."

Again, He states, people want flashy warnings, but ignore the ones they already have.

Indeed, 2 Peter invokes the flood as well:

> I want you to recall both the predictions foretold by the holy prophets and the commandment of the Lord and Savior through your apostles. Above all, understand this: In the last days blatant scoffers will come, being propelled by their own evil urges and saying, "Where is his promised return? For ever since our ancestors died, all things have continued as they were from the beginning of creation." For they deliberately suppress this fact, that by the word of God heavens existed long ago and an earth was formed out of water and by means of water. Through these things the world existing at that time was destroyed when it was deluged with water. But by the same word the present heavens and earth have been reserved for fire, by being kept for the day of judgment and destruction of the ungodly.

The point keeps being made over and over again that God has been veritably screaming from the mountaintops that wrath is coming (Read Zephaniah! or Joel! or Revelation!), but the truth is that in the last days, people say that God is asleep; that nothing will change; that people never believe wrath is coming.  Whether it is the parable of the Foolish Virgins, or the Parable of the Vineyard, or the Parable of the Wheat and the Tares, Jesus is forever saying, "[People get ready](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVamMjrv3og)  Judgement is coming." And yet, people ignore it.

My personal favorite - Paul writes with unassailable logic in Romans 13:

> Wake up! The day of our salvation is nearer now then when we first believed!

People live in willing ignorance, as Jesus says in Matthew 24:

> For just like the days of Noah were, so the coming of the Son of Man will be. For in those days before the flood, people were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until the day Noah entered the ark. And they knew nothing until the flood came and took them all away. It will be the same at the coming of the Son of Man. Then there will be two men in the field; one will be taken and one left. There will be two women grinding grain with a mill; one will be taken and one left.

In short, yes, God did say he wouldn't flood again - but He did say He will return, and that will be a scary day.  He is already shouting from the rooftops, "Repent."  The question is, are people listening?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Yes, He would:

**Amos 3:7**

> 7 Surely the Lord God will do nothing, but he revealeth his secret unto his servants the prophets.